# Front panel audio connection not working after restart

Tags: 11.04, sound

Since my HDMI audio does not work with the open source drivers (doubt it can be fixed, Google'd everywhere), I have to use an audio jack (which is fine). My 3.5mm connection on the back works fine (which is where the speakers are connected to) but the one on front panel (part of the tower/case) stopped working after I restarted. This is all a fresh install, but just to test it, I did another fresh install, updated, and watched a YouTube video to check if the audio worked (and it did), then I just normally restarted and it stops working again. I'm using Ubuntu 11.04.

Answer (score 1):

Just the same. But, I've found a solution. Changing FP audio setting in BIOS to AUTO (HD mode), then restart, swithing back to ENABLED (AC97 mode) and restart again. It's quite annoying, but I can't see any better solution =(

Answer (score 1):

That is often caused by bad alsa/pulseaudio settings:

Look for the sound managger output section especially the output connector field.
It's values are often wrong-textured, so worth to try all of them.